# ByteArrayOutputStream to a FileBody

Tags: android, image, upload, http-post

I have a Uri to an image that was either taken or selected from the Gallery that I want to load up and compress as a JPEG with 75% quality.  I believe I have achieved that with the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
```

Not that I have tucked it into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` called `bos` I need to then add it to a `MultipartEntity` in order to `HTTP POST` it to a website.  **What I can't figure out is how to convert the ByteArrayOutputStream to a FileBody.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [`ByteArrayBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.html) instead (available since HTTPClient 4.1), despite its name it takes a file name, too:

```
ContentBody mimePart = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), "filename");
```

If you are stuck with HTTPClient 4.0, use [`InputStreamBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html) instead:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
ContentBody mimePart = new InputStreamBody(in, "filename")
```

(Both classes also have constructors that take an addtional MIME type string)

Answer (score 2):

i hope it may help some one , you can mention the file type as "image/jpeg" in FileBody as below code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "url");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
            reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody(pass));
File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/4.jpg");
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
reqEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }

            Log.e("Response for POst", s.toString());
```

need to add jar files httpclient-4.2.2.jar,httpmime-4.2.2.jar in your project.