# Compress camera image before upload

Tags: android, image, upload, camera, compression

I am using this code (from [www.internetria.com](http://www.internetria.com/blog/2013/04/12/android-enviar-imagenes-por-webservice/)) to take a photo and upload to a server:

onCreate:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(foto));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

onActivityResult:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foto));

        File file = new File(foto);
        if (file.exists()) {
            UploaderFoto nuevaTarea = new UploaderFoto();
            nuevaTarea.execute(foto);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se ha realizado la foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

UploaderFoto:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
String miFoto = "";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    miFoto = params[0];
    try { 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://servidor.com/up.php");
        File file = new File(miFoto);
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody foto = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("fotoUp", foto);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I want to compress the image, because the size is too big.

I don't know how to add `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);` to my app

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445929/2809351

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look over here: [ByteArrayOutputStream to a FileBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832598/bytearrayoutputstream-to-a-filebody)

Something along these lines should work:

replace

```
File file = new File(miFoto);
ContentBody foto = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
```

with

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(miFoto)
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
ContentBody foto = new InputStreamBody(in, "image/jpeg", "filename");
```

If file size is still an issue you may want to scale the picture in addition to compressing it.

Comment: InputStreamBody is deprecated. Now what?

Comment: ContentBody foto = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), filename);

Comment: this probably make OutOfMemory exception in big images. you can use this to avoid any problem : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: I am also using the compress function from Bitmap but my Problem is that my Pictures look strange after compression. Maybe the reason because I'm not using a ByteArrayOutpuStream? I am using a normal Outputstream

Answer (score 6):

Convert image to [Google WebP format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery1) it will save you lots of bytes see the following two articles you can also convert webP into JPG/PNG/GIF whatever you want on server side.

[Java Wrapper of Google WebP API](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio)

[How to check out Google WebP library and use it in Android as native library](http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2014/02/webp-in-android.html)

First, you need to get pixels from Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] pixels = buffer.array();
```

Then, you can get WebP byte array.

```
int stride = bytes / height;
int quality = 100;
byte[] encoded = libwebp.WebPEncodeRGBA(pixels, width, height, stride, quality);
```

Test.png (Size: 106KB)
[image: Test.png (Size: 106KB)]
Test.webp(Size: 48KB)
[image: Test.webp(Size: 48KB)]

Answer (score 2):

Using okhttp I upload like this:

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG
                        = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");

                //Compress Image
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath());
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);

                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("photo", fileToUpload.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, bos.toByteArray()))
                        .build();

                request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(urlToUploadTo)
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();

                try {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    if (response != null) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            responseResult = response.body().string();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Such a useful answer it is! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the `compressImage()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Uri fileUri;
private ImageView img_forCompress;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Ibook";
static File mediaFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img_forCompress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_forCompress);

    img_forCompress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    Log.e("path", "media file:-" + mediaFile);
    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.e("path", "" + mediaFile.toString());
    String filename = mediaFile.toString();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);

    compressImage(bitmap);

}



private void compressImage(Bitmap photo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int imageWidth = photo.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = photo.getHeight();
    long length = mediaFile.length();
    int newHeight = 0;
    int newWidth = 0;

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "oldwidth="+imageWidth+",oldHeight="+imageHeight,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Old Image gheight and width---------", imageWidth + "-------"
            + imageHeight + " and Size is -- " + length);
    if (imageHeight > 1500 || imageWidth > 1500) {
        if (imageHeight > imageWidth) {
            Log.e("height is more", "true");
            newHeight = 1200;
            newWidth = (newHeight * imageWidth / imageHeight);
        }
        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
            Log.e("width is more", "true");
            newWidth = 1200;
            newHeight = (newWidth * imageHeight / imageWidth);
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "newwidth="+newWidth+",newHeight="+newHeight,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("new Image gheight and width---------", newHeight + "-------"
```