# Intent only getting images from the back camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-image

My app is supposed to get a picture from the **gallery** and display it in an `ImageView`, I am getting what I want with all the images EXCEPT the ones I took with my **back camera**, they show up in the gallery for me to pick and even return the path, but all I get is blankness in my `ImageView`.

This is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

my onActivityResult code is this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works with images taken with my **front camera**.

I haven't tried the app on another phone but if this happens in mine, chances are someone else will have the same problem.

Comment: Please add the code where you display the image in your imageview.

Comment: How are you setting Image to ImageView, show that code.

Comment: Back camera images are usually pretty large to handle. Compress them with Bitmap Factory before showing in imageView

Comment: Indeed. And meanwhile you should check if `bitmap==null` after statement `Bitmap bitmap = .....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the size of the image.

I've successfully fixed the same issue with scaling the `Bitmap` before displaying in the `ImageView`

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri);

try {
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri);

        float rotationInDegrees = 0;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION},
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int col = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);
            if (col != -1)
                rotationInDegrees = cursor.getInt(col);
            cursor.close();
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);

        int width, height;
        double aspectRatio;
        aspectRatio = (double) sourceBitmap.getWidth() / sourceBitmap.getHeight();
        if (sourceBitmap.getHeight() > sourceBitmap.getWidth()) {
            height = MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION;
            width = (int) (height * aspectRatio);
        } else {
            width = MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION;
            height = (int) (width / aspectRatio);
        }
        sourceBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, width, height, false);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("ImageHelper@getImageFromUri: IOException");
}
```

Comment: `scaling the Bitmap before displaying`. Interesting. But in many cases you cannot scale it in this way as `sourceBitmap` will be `null` already at first statement because of lack of memory. You are not even checking for `null` now.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

the reason is i think memory out of index.
please refer this link [Compress camera image before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594152/compress-camera-image-before-upload) you can under stand

Comment: Oh, maybe it is the problem, I'll check the code soon. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even after compressing if you cannot get it, then try using some library for picking the images from the gallery.

Comment: It does get images from the gallery EXCEPT the ones taken with the back camera, a library would surely solve my problem, but I want to know why is this thing happening in the first place.